# Unpacking list of tuples of pixels

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

I've been trying to solve this textbook question for a while but am a bit stuck.

Question:

> We have provided a module `image` with a procedure
>
> ```
> file2image(filename)
> ```
>
> that reads in an image stored in a file in the 
>   `.png` format. Import this procedure and invoke it,
>   providing as argument the name of a file containing an image in this format, assigning the returned
>   value to variable `data`
>
> The value of data is a list of lists, and `data[y][x]` is the intensity of pixel `(x,y)`. Pixel
>   `(0,0)` is at the bottom-left of the image, and pixel `(width-1, height-1)` is at the top-right.
>   The intensity of a pixel is a number between 0 (black) and 255 (white).
>   Use a comprehension to assign to a list `pts` the set of complex numbers `x+yi` such that the
>   image intensity of pixel `(x, y)` is less than 120.

Here is the relevant method that was provided

```
def file2image(path):
    """ Reads an image into a list of lists of pixel values (tuples with
        three values). This is a color image. """
    (w, h, p, m) = png.Reader(filename = path).asRGBA() # force RGB and alpha
    return [_flat2boxed(r) for r in p]
```

I'm really unsure how to parse the 3 values as a comprehension, anyone has a guess?

The way I understand the data structure goes like : [[(x,y,z)],[(x,y,z)]...etc]

So my code is obviously wrong but I tried

```
    data = img.file2image("img01.png")
    data = img.color2gray(data)
    pts = [(x,y,z) for (x,y,z) in data]
    plot(pts)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a pretty terrible description text to describe the objective, here's my take at comprehension of list of lists and list of lists of lists

```
>>> [[v for v in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> [[[v for v in range(5)] for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]], [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]], [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]], [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]], [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]]
>>>
```

the `_` in my `for` loops throws away the variable coming out of the iterator since I don't need to store it